# How to calculate the distance to the parent element in CSS?

Tags: css

When I have an element in a flexbox parent element, is there a way to get the distance to the parent element left/top boundary?

I would like to use a CSS animation to distribute the objects from `0,0` to their actual positions like this

```
@keyframes distribute_elements {
    from {
        translateX(calc(distance_to_parent_left));
        translateY(calc(distance_to_parent_top));
    }   
    to {
        /* nothing special */
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS as it cann't **detect** anything.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't an actual programming language. You can't gather data using CSS. Javascript and jQuery are your only two options for the task you're trying to accomplish. You could also take the two numbers and calculate it yourself...

Javascript:

```
 var child = document.getElementById('insertChildElementID').offsetTop;
 var parent = document.getElementById('insertParentElementID').offsetTop;
 var distance = child - parent;`
```

JQuery:

```
var child = $('#insertChildElementID').position.top;
var parent = $('#insertParentElementID').position.top;
var distance = child - parent;
```

For a better jQyuery explanation go to [this website](https://api.jquery.com/position/).

For a better Javascript explanation go to [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp).

Comment: Using Javascript is no problem, but I try to use pure CSS. CSS3 is quite powerful and tools like the ``vh`` unit and the ``calc()`` function allow for much in pure CSS. I would really like to know if there is a nice trick to do it with CSS.